# eb init not showing Mumbai region

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I want to create an EBS django application using EB CLI, I knew the procedure also as I have already done it for other region(Oregon). Now I want to create another new EBS application for Mumbai region, whenever I do `eb init` to configure region , it's not showing option for Mumbai region.What is the problem?. Even I tried do change configuration for my existing app using `eb init -i` there also it's not showing Mumbai region.

Following are the options for me:

```
piyush@piyush-ThinkPad ~/abc/xyz $ eb init -i

Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
7) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
8) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
9) ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
10) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
11) cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
(default is 3):
```

Comment: Is your `awsebcli` upgraded to the lastest version?

Comment: Is `ebcli` and `awsebcli` is same?

Comment: My point is, the old versions of aws related tools don't have newly added region. So check if there is an update for whatever tool you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others in comments make sure to use an up to date version of the eb cli tool

```
fhenri:~$ eb --version
EB CLI 3.8.3 (Python 2.7.1)
fhenri:~$ eb init -i

Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-south-1 : Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
7) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
8) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
9) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
10) ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
11) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
12) cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
13) us-east-2 : US East (Ohio)
(default is 3):
```